# Error TF255217: TfsIntegration extended properties, while trying to upgrade from TFS2005

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration, tfs-2005

I am trying to import TFS 2005 into TFS 2010 using tfsconfig import command. When running the command I receive error TF255217: The specific database (TfsIntegration) is not upgradable. After researching, I believe this is due to missing extended properties on the database. However, looking back at the original TFS 2005 database reveals it has no extended properties either. I believe the properties I need are:

- `TFS_INSTANCE`
- `TFS_INT_PROTOCOL_VERSION`
- `TFS_PRODUCT_VERSION`

How can I find out what these properties should be set to?

Comment: Can someone with a TFS2005 installation share what their TfsIntegration's database extended properties are?

Answer (score 0):

I tried upgrading from tfs 2008 to 2012 and using tfsconfig and get some bizzare issues
see [migrate data from TFS 2008 to an already working TFS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972422/migrate-data-from-tfs-2008-to-an-already-working-tfs-2012/21383539#21383539). what I did and might as well help you is do a double migration.
Create a temp VM with new sqlserver copy the db's to there install TFS2008 and choose the upgrade scenario and afterward migrate it to 2010. 
this double upgrade solved me allot of errors.